# Questions falling under Interest tags are too light...

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

The appearance of questions that contain tags in my interest list is too light. If my (laptop) monitor is not aligned in the right way, I can't see the darker background. Even if the monitor is properly aligned, the contrast is quite slight, and hard to notice.

So in any case, the messages I'm interested are not easy to spot.

Is it possible to make the contrast sharper please?

Ohad.

Answer (score 2):

I have darkened the background color for interesting questions. The change will be the next deployment.

Answer (score 1):

I agree, I think the interesting questions should be made more visible.

(Not because of poor monitors, viewing angles, etc., but simply because the difference between uninteresting and interesting questions is too slight.)

Comment: That is different from what Ohad is talking about, because he implies that if the monitor is aligned in the right way, he can see the darker background.

Comment: Of course I *can* see the darker background, but the colour is so light that interesting questions aren't exactly eye-catching. If I quickly scroll through the front page, interesting questions are easy to miss.

Comment: No, that is not my point.  My point is that Ohad is asking for a color change _for the monitor not properly aligned_.  You are asking for a color change for the monitor properly set up.  If this is true, the problem you are reporting is more serious than the problem Ohad is reporting.

Comment: I'm actually asking for a change for both reasons. I'll edit the original report accordingly.